# C not seeing my function correctly?

Tags: c

Im new to C. I have a function defined as such:

```
/*
 * Draws an image in mode3 USING DMA.
 * int x x coordinate 
 * int y y coordinate
 * int width Width of the image (Note may not be the same width as the GBA)
 * int height Height of the image (Note may not be the same height as the GBA)
 * const u16* pointer to the first element in the image
 */
void drawImage3(int x, int y, int width, int height, const u16* image)
{
    int r;
    for (r=0; r<height; r++) {  

            DMA[3].src = &image;
            DMA[3].dst = &videoBuffer[OFFSET(x+width, y, 240)];
            DMA[3].cnt = width | DMA_SOURCE_FIXED| DMA_ON | DMA_DESTINATION_INCREMENT; 
            image = &image + (r * width);

    }

}
```

In a .h file I include in my main program I have this:

```
void drawImage3(int x, int y, int width, int height, const u16* image);
```

where u16 means an unsigned short and is defined elsewhere.

And these, too, are in my .h file:

```
extern unsigned short *videoBuffer;
extern const unsigned short *pt;
```

in another h file is an array of 1024 const unsigned shorts.

In my main.c file I call my function like this:

```
pt = imgArray;
drawImage3(25,25, img_WIDTH, img_HEIGHT, pt);
```

I get a lot of errors.

```
Program.c:22: error: data definition has no type or storage class
Program.c:22: error: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'pt'
Program.c:22: error: conflicting types for 'pt'
myLib.h:21: note: previous declaration of 'pt' was here
Program.c:22: error: initializer element is not constant
Program.c:23: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before numeric constant
Program.c:23: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before numeric constant
Program.c:23: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before numeric constant
Program.c:23: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before numeric constant
Program.c:23: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'pt'
Program.c:23: error: data definition has no type or storage class
Program.c:23: error: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'drawImage3'
Program.c:23: error: conflicting types for 'drawImage3'
myLib.h:117: note: previous declaration of 'drawImage3' was here
```

Any ideas of whats going on here?

-------EDITS

Yes, Oli, you are right about the first error. Thanks! I've edited my function as such and that error is gone. I've also made my *pt and extern.

Program.c:

```
//Philip Johnson
#include <stdio.h>
#include "img.h"
#include <unistd.h>
#include "myLib.h"
#include "text.h"

typedef struct        // This typedef defines a new type called MOVOBJ
{                     // which are structures that hold all the info for
    int row;          // a single movable object
    int col;
    int rdel;
    int cdel;
    u16 color;

} MOVOBJ;

MOVOBJ newcharacter, car1, car2, car3;
int size = 5;
int speed = 2;
int checkforend = 0;
pt = imgArray;
drawImage3(25,25, img_WIDTH, img_HEIGHT, pt);
int main(){ //....and so on from there
```

Comment: Isn't the first error due to the same problem as in [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6639256/pointer-to-first-element-in-array-c)?

Comment: Please post the first part of your main.c file.

Comment: Also, declaring non-`extern` variables in a header file is usually a bad idea.

Comment: I've made some edits to the question in an attempt to figure this out. I see I'm getting a lot of downvotes...is there anything I can do to try to clarify my question?

Answer (score 1):

You probably mean `u16* pt = imgArray;` - if you're declaring new variables in C you must give the type.